# Many-to-many relationship RavenDb: Document structure and index

Tags: c#, indexing, nosql, ravendb, ravendb4

How to you build a NoSQL model and index (preferably for RavenDb v4) for the following relational schema?

> Document type `Contact`, where each record can have multiple additional properties (type of the property is defined in `CustomField` and the value in `ContactCustomField`)
>   [image]

Considering a need to filter/sort on the highlighted fields in one query (all fields from the Contact plus custom fields).

---

Possible options as I see:

**Option #1**

Naturally, I'd imagine the following persistent models:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Id      { get; set; }
    public string Name    { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone   { get; set; }
    // Where the key is CustomField.Id and the value is ContactCustomField.Value
    public Dictionary<string, string> CustomValues { get; set; }
}

public class CustomField
{
    public string Id          { get; set; }
    public string Code        { get; set; }
    public string DataType    { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

However, building an index for a query like below (sorry for a mixed syntax) puzzles me:

```
SELECT Name, Address, Phone, CustomValues
FROM Contact
WHERE Name LIKE '*John*' AND CustomValues.Any(v => v.Key == "11" && v.Value == "student")
```

**Option #2**

Another approach would be keeping a normalised structure (as shown on the picture above). Then it would work - I'd just have to include `ContactCustomField` in the query for `Contact`.

The downside would be not utilising benefits of NoSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer** (29 June 2018)

The key to success is in one undervalued Raven's feature - [Indexes with Dynamic Fields](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/Csharp/indexes/using-dynamic-fields). It allows to keep logical data structure and avoids creating a [fanout index](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/indexes/fanout-indexes).

The way to use is to build collections like described above in option #1:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Id      { get; set; }
    public string Name    { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone   { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> CustomFields { get; set; }
}

public class CustomField
{
    public string Id          { get; set; }
    public string Code        { get; set; }
    public string DataType    { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

where `Contact.CustomFields.Key` is a reference to `CustonField.Id` and `Contact.CustomFields.Value` stores a value for that custom field.

In order to filter/search on the custom fields, we need the following index:

```
public class MyIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Contact>
{
    public MyIndex()
    {
        Map = contacts =>
            from e in contacts
            select new
            {
                _ = e.CustomFields.Select( x => CreateField ($"{nameof(Contact.CustomFields)}_{x.Key}", x.Value))
            };
    }
}
```

That index will cover all key-value pairs of the dictionary as they were ordinary properties of the `Contact`.

**Gotcha**

There is a big gotcha if you write queries in C# with using the usual Query object (`IRavenQueryable` type), rather than `RQL` or `DocumentQuery`. It's in the way we named the dynamic fields - it's a compound name in specific format: `dictionary_name + underscore + key_name`. It allows us to build queries like

```
var q = s.Query<Person, MyIndex>()
                .Where(p => p.CustomFields["Age"].Equals(4));
```

Which under the hood gets converted into RQL:

```
from index 'MyIndex' where CustomFields_Age = $p1
```

It's undocumented and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/YvPZFIn5GVg) is my discussion with Oren Eini (aka Ayende Rahien) where you can learn more on the subject.

P.S. My general recommendation would be to interact with Raven via `DocumentQuery` rather than the usual `Query` ([link](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/indexes/querying/query-vs-document-query)), as LINQ integration is still quite weak and devs may keep stumbling upon bugs here and there.

---

**Initial answer** (9 June 2018)

As it was [suggested](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/dxOjF01xhBI/KwWCVlfggTwJ) by Oren Eini (aka Ayende Rahien), the way to go is option #2 - including a separate `ContactCustomField` collection in the queries.

So in spite of using a NoSQL database, relational approach is the only way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

For this you probably want to use Map-Reduced indexes.

Map:

```
docs.Contacts.SelectMany(doc => (doc, next) => new{
// Contact Fields
doc.Id,
doc.Name,
doc.Address,
doc.Phone,
doc.CustomFieldLoaded = LoadDocument<string>(doc.CustomValueField, "CustomFieldLoaded"),
doc.CustomValues
});
```

Reduce:

```
from result in results
group result by {result.Id, result.Name, result.Address, result.Phone, result.CustomValues, result.CustomFieldLoaded} into g
select new{
g.Key.Id,
g.Key.Name,
g.Key.Address,
g.Key.Phone,
g.Key.CustomFieldLoaded = new {},
g.Key.CustomValues = g.CustomValues.Select(c=> g.Key.CustomFieldLoaded[g.Key.CustomValues.IndexOf(c)])
}
```

Your document would look something like this:

```
{
"Name": "John Doe",
"Address": "1234 Elm St",
"Phone": "000-000-0000",
CustomValues: "{COLLECTION}/{DOCUMENTID}"
}
```

This would load the contact and then load the relational documents' data.

I haven't tested this exact example but it's based off of a working example that I have implemented in my own project. You may need to do some tweaking.

You will of course need to tweak it to include many documents but it should give you a basic idea of how to use relationships.

You should also checkout documentation for [document relationships](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/Csharp/client-api/how-to/handle-document-relationships).

I hope this helps.